# How to rename duplicated columns after join?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to use join with 3 dataframe, but there are some columns we don't need or have some duplicate name with other dataframes, so I want to drop some columns like below:

```py
result_df = (aa_df.join(bb_df, 'id', 'left')
  .join(cc_df, 'id', 'left')
  .withColumnRenamed(bb_df.status, 'user_status'))
```

Please note that `status` column is in two dataframes, i.e. `aa_df` and `bb_df`.

The above doesn't work. I also tried to use `withColumn`, but the new column is created, and the old column is still existed.

Comment: I don't think the question is a duplicate of the one given as there are two issues related, i.e. 1. how to avoid join column to appear twice in the output and 2. how to access columns of the same name that are not part of join condition. I think this question is about 2. Just 2 grosze.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are trying to rename the `status` column of `bb_df` dataframe then you can do so while joining as

```
result_df = aa_df.join(bb_df.withColumnRenamed('status', 'user_status'),'id', 'left').join(cc_df, 'id', 'left')
```

Answer (score 12):

> I want to use join with 3 dataframe, but there are some columns we don't need or have some duplicate name with other dataframes

That's a fine use case for aliasing a Dataset using `alias` or `as` operators.

> **alias(alias: String): Dataset[T]** or **alias(alias: Symbol): Dataset[T]**
> Returns a new Dataset with an alias set. Same as as.
>
> **as(alias: String): Dataset[T]** or **as(alias: Symbol): Dataset[T]**
> Returns a new Dataset with an alias set.

(And honestly I did only now see the `Symbol`-based variants.)

**NOTE** There are two `as` operators, `as` for aliasing and `as` for type mapping. Consult the [Dataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) API.

After you've aliases a Dataset, you can reference columns using `[alias].[columnName]` format. This is particularly handy with joins and *star column dereferencing* using `*`.

```
val ds1 = spark.range(5)
scala> ds1.as('one).select($"one.*").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+

val ds2 = spark.range(10)
// Using joins with aliased datasets
// where clause is in a longer form to demo how ot reference columns by alias
scala> ds1.as('one).join(ds2.as('two)).where($"one.id" === $"two.id").show
+---+---+
| id| id|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
|  4|  4|
+---+---+
```

> so I want to drop some columns like below

My general recommendation is not to `drop` columns, but `select` what you want to include in the result. That makes life more predictable as you know what you get (not what you don't). I was told that our brains work by positives which could also make a point for `select`.

So, as you asked and I showed in the above example, the result has two columns of the same name `id`. The question is how to have only one.

There are at least two answers with using the variant of `join` operator with the join columns or condition included (as you did show in your question), but that would not answer your real question about "dropping unwanted columns", would it?

Given I prefer `select` (over `drop`), I'd do the following to have a single `id` column:

```
val q = ds1.as('one)
  .join(ds2.as('two))
  .where($"one.id" === $"two.id")
  .select("one.*") // <-- select columns from "one" dataset
scala> q.show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
```

Regardless of the reasons why you asked the question (which could also be answered with the points I raised above), let me answer the (burning) question how to use `withColumnRenamed` when there are two matching columns (after `join`).

Let's assume you ended up with the following query and so you've got two `id` columns (per join side).

```
val q = ds1.as('one)
  .join(ds2.as('two))
  .where($"one.id" === $"two.id")
scala> q.show
+---+---+
| id| id|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
|  4|  4|
+---+---+
```

`withColumnRenamed` won't work for this use case since it does not accept aliased column names.

```
scala> q.withColumnRenamed("one.id", "one_id").show
+---+---+
| id| id|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  1|
|  2|  2|
|  3|  3|
|  4|  4|
+---+---+
```

You could `select` the columns you're interested in as follows:

```
scala> q.select("one.id").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+

scala> q.select("two.*").show
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  0|
|  1|
|  2|
|  3|
|  4|
+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the docs : [withColumnRenamed()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed)
You need to pass the name of the existing column and the new name to the function. Both of these should be strings.

```
result_df = aa_df.join(bb_df,'id', 'left').join(cc_df, 'id', 'left').withColumnRenamed('status', 'user_status')
```

If you have 'status' columns in 2 dataframes, you can use them in the join as `aa_df.join(bb_df, ['id','status'], 'left')` assuming aa_df and bb_df have the common column. This way you will not end up having 2 'status' columns.

Comment: But "status" exists two dataframe, as you mention above ,it can throw a exception:'status' column is ambiguous

Comment: What do you mean, status exists two dataframe?

Comment: Does it exist in `aa_df` and `bb_df` and `cc_df` both?

Comment: yeah, so I think your method is not right